# "apt-get --print-uris" to list URI for downloading extra functionality package for amarok,reqonk

Tags: apt, updates, amarok

Hello
I do not have internet connection at my home. So i use "apt-get --print-uris" to list the http's and take it to other PC with internet connection and use wget to download them.
I am facing difficulty about how to list the http's that amarok will download from for the extra functionality (like mp3 codecs). KDE deamon is showing me that these packages are needed for extra functionality of amarok but i don't know how to list their http's.

"apt-get --print-uris upgrade" does not list http's need for amarok/reqonk.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for your answers. 
I think i have found a way to list the http's for downloading codecs. It is not that efficient though. I happen to notice that "qapt-batch" tries to install these package. First I open the notification
[image: notification]

Then I click install selected. Then I can see the Packages
[image: package list]

it would have been very useful for me if I could copy the package names with my mouse so that i could apply `apt-get --print -uris install packagename_s`
But i cannot copy the package names. So after giving authentication i opened `/var/log/auth.log`
and there i could see the last command authentication `qapt-batch --install packagename_s`
I copied them from there. Then I extracted http's using --print-uris.

Comment: Can anybody tell me form which file does the system notification helper collects the package_names form ? If i can find that file the work would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to know from experience that Amarok installs package [libxine1-ffmpeg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libxine1-ffmpeg) for MP3 support.

For a general solution, try watching the terminal output of `amarok --debug`. I don't know for certain, but I would be surprised if the package name wasn't listed in there somewhere.

Comment: amarok --debug didn't list the package name.